# Combining Lua binaries

Tags: c++, lua, compilation, binary-data

I have several Lua scripts that all `require` a few scripts that define some common functions. This creates a situation similar to the header system in C where I'm re-compiling the same code over and over again. This isn't desirable because these scripts are compiled at runtime. I already have a system to cache the binaries after the script has been compiled but I'm wondering if there's a way to compile the `require`d scripts and the scripts that use them separately then combine them.

Comment: `require` is a function so it runs post-compile (if the compiled script is called and the statement is in the flow of logic). It doesn't necessarily cause anything else to be compiled as explained by @Paul. Often the single string function call syntax is used so it might not look like a function call but it is.

Answer (score 3):

If those Lua scripts that call require are executed in the same state, then "required" scripts are only executed once as their returned values are cached in `package.loaded` table. If you are "requiring" them from scripts executed in different Lua states, then you can combine and pre-compile the scripts and then load them once; you can use `luac` to do this.